# For loop in using the timeout angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` . I have a function like this -

```
for(var i=0; i < uploadService.getOrphans().length; i++ ) {
     var orphan = uploadService.getOrphans()[i].attributes.text;
                  $timeout(function () {
        //Here I am using a orphan but its taking only last element. 
      }, 0);

}
```

Here, I want to use the orphan but it's taking only last element into consideration. Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IIFE you can save the context of i for each iteration

```
for(var i=0; i < uploadService.getOrphans().length; i++ ) {
     (function (index) {
       var orphan = uploadService.getOrphans()[index].attributes.text;
       $timeout(function () {
        //Here I am using a orphan but its taking only last element. 
       }, 0);
     })(i)

}
```